# What is PHPCI – what is a build?

Tags: php-ci

Please forgive me if this is a silly question. I'm not hating on phpci, I'm just trying to understand it:

PHP is a scripting language... so one doesn't really "build" an application like you do in C++. You just write the code and the application runs. So I'm not grokking the concept of what a "build" is?

At first I thought it was about deployment – because that would be super useful – a button on your server's dev portal that you click and hey presto the latest version is deployed to production from git. But that's apparently not what phpci does.

It looks like I can use it to run unit tests... but then I could just run the tests without phpci. So again I'm not understanding what to expect from a "build". What's the benefit of performing a build?

At the moment it seems counter-productive to me:- like a (much) slower version of git pull but which clones the code into a folder that doesn't have a vhost, so you can't browse it.

Confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPCI is a test-runner framework with a web GUI. A "build" in this context refers to a given set of tests that were run against a given release (which it gets from your repo). UI-wise it's a bit like Jenkins in terms of seeing a history of "builds" and their success.

Unlike Jenkins however it is not used to "build" your code in the sense of deploying it to a given environment.